# Getting html error 301, which return exact same link

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I’m trying to get the content of a HTML page with a Node.js app.
I found this code: [In Node.js / Express, how do I "download" a page and gets its HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801453/in-node-js-express-how-do-i-download-a-page-and-gets-its-html) (yojimbo answer), which seems to work well. When I try to start the code, I get the HTML result of 301 Moved Permanently, nut the redirect link is the same as the one I sent!

```
var util = require("util"),
    http = require("http");

var options = {
    host: "www.mylink.com",
    port: 80,
    path: "/folder/content.xml"
};

var content = "";   

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
    res.setEncoding("utf8");
    res.on("data", function (chunk) {
        content += chunk;
    });

    res.on("end", function () {
        util.log(content);
    });
});

req.end();
```

And the return is:

```
30 Jul 13:08:52 - <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://mylink.com/folder/content.xml"<here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<adress>Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at www.mylink.com Port 80</adress>
</body></html>
```

Is it moved permanently to the same place or is it just some kind of security on the server? Or did I made a mistake in the code? (but it work on google and all the other site I tested).

I doubt it s the ".xml" which cause a problem since I even tested with page in pdf without problem (just a bunch of non readable chars).

Following a discussion with the client, I’ll get the page in another way (downloading it directly), which works OK. I still accept the answer of c.Pu.1, but I’m still wondering why the redirect link is the same as the link the app follow.

Comment: Notice that you request `/folder/content.xml` and redirect to `/folder.content.xml`. It's not the same url.

Comment: Sorry, it s a typo, I had to recopy the message from another computer

Comment: Not the same URL: request should be "www.mylink.com/folder/content.xml", but there's no "www" in the response. I had the same issue, but in my case, the server was requiring a trailing "/" on the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 301 status code indicates the requested resource has been moved and that a client must perform a redirect to the link included in the response's **Location** header. The `http` module doesn't follow redirects(status codes 3xx) by default.

You can use the [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) module, which is said to perform redirects.

> Request is designed to be the simplest way possible to make http
>   calls. It supports HTTPS and follows redirects by default.

To do it manually, read the **Location** header from the response and initiate a new request to that URI.

```
var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
    res.setEncoding("utf8");
    if(res.statusCode === 301 || res.statusCode === 302) {
        var newRequestUri = res.headers.location;
        http.request({hostname: newRequestUri}, function(res) {
            //read response
        }
    }
    res.on("data", function (chunk) {
        content += chunk;
    });

    res.on("end", function () {
        util.log(content);
    });
});
```

Comment: I could do that, but the things that intrigate me is that I get the exact same link in the redirect page.

Answer (score 0):

If the redirect link in the "Location:" header is the same as the originally requested link, then the server is either misconfigured or broken.

Note that the link in the response body is only there as a convenience to humans and should not be considered authoritative. Only the "Location:" field in the HTTP Response header should be used to locate a redirected resource.