# Load dynamic html with nodejs

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, http, httprequest

I'm pretty new with NodeJs.
I'm trying to download some html from a website in order to parse it and present some information for debug.
I try with success with http module ([see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801453/in-node-js-express-how-do-i-download-a-page-and-gets-its-html)), but in this way when I print chunk:

```
var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
    res.setEncoding("utf8");
    res.on("data", function (chunk) {
       console.log(chunk);
    });
});
```

I don't get all html that is loaded dynamically with ajax for instance:

```
<div class="container">
  ::before
      <div class="row">
        ::before
....
</div>
```

Are there any other [module](https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/crawler) that can help me on this goal?

Thanks!

## update

I would like to share with you my success (thanks to @oKonyk).

- npm install phantomjs
- create your script
- use the same code suggested by @oKonyk

note that if you're running your script locally, you need to set this options:

```
options = { 'web-security': 'no' };
phantom.create({parameters: options}, function() {});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to capture dynamically built pages you have to render them in browser. There are several options to do that with node.js.

I would suggest using [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org), which is a so called headless browser.

In order to proof the concept you can install `npm install phantomjs -g` globally. Create test script 'google.js' with following content:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
console.log('The default user agent is ' + page.settings.userAgent);
page.settings.userAgent = 'SpecialAgent';
page.open('http://www.google.org', function(status) {
  if (status !== 'success') {
    console.log('Unable to access network');
  } else {
    var html = page.evaluate(function() {
      return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML;
    });
    console.log(html);
  }
  phantom.exit();
});
```

Then run it as `phantomjs google.js`

You will get printed whole DOM of the page (at lest everything within `<html>` tags), which different from raw response that you are getting with `http` module.

Later you can use `phantom` within your node project (more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11259818/is-it-possible-to-run-phantomjs-from-node-js-as-a-command-line-argument)).

Comment: Thanks for answer @oKonyk. With this solution I get "phantom stdout: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101: A network error occurred in synchronous requests." I'm running script from localhost, so I suppose that I have to setup "--web-security=false", isn't it? Where can I set this option? I'm running my script with node.

Comment: I've created phantom.create({'web-security':'no'}, function (ph) {}); but errors still appear!

Comment: So the URL that you are trying to access is `localhost`? If it's just any public URL, I could try to access it from my system... When you are saying that you run your script with node, do you mean you have your `phantomjs` process as child process on your main node script?