# NodeJS HttpGet method not working on Wiki

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, http, http-get

### Objective

Download the HTML of a Wiki Page.

### Background

I am trying to download the HTML of a Wiki page (http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Mods_2.0) to parse for information. To achieve this I am using NodeJS and I am using its [HTTP Request methods](https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.7/api/all.html#http.request).

### Code

I have a very simple code file which merely accesses the website and tries to print its contents:

```
"use strict";

var http = require("http");

var options = {
  host: "http://warframe.wikia.com",
  port: 80,
  path: 'wiki/Mods_2.0',
  method: "GET"
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {

  console.log("STATUS: " + res.statusCode);
  console.log("HEADERS: " + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
  res.setEncoding('utf8');

  res.on("data", function (chunk) {
    console.log("BODY: " + chunk);
  });
});

req.end();
```

### Problem

The problem is that no matter what I do, nor what I try, I always get the following error output:

```
Debugger listening on port 15454 events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND http://warframe.wikia.com http://warframe.wikia.com:80
    at errnoException (dns.js:27:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:78:26)


Process exited with code: 1
```

I am fairly sure that I am building the URL incorrectly, but somehow I can't understand how to fix this!

### What I tried

My approach is based on the contents this discussion [In Node.js / Express, how do I "download" a page and gets its HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801453/in-node-js-express-how-do-i-download-a-page-and-gets-its-html?noredirect=1&lq=1).

I tried several combinations of the URL path in the `options` variable, only to get different versions of the same error.

I also read [In Node.js / Express, how do I "download" a page and gets its HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801453/in-node-js-express-how-do-i-download-a-page-and-gets-its-html), however that discussion has a different problem (it focuses on streaming, which is not my objective).

### Questions

1 - I am fairly sure this is a simple error but I cannot see it. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `http` in the url and add `/` in the path:

```
"use strict";

var http = require("http");

var options = {
  host: "warframe.wikia.com",
  port: 80,
  path: '/wiki/Mods_2.0',
  method: "GET"
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {

  console.log("STATUS: " + res.statusCode);
  console.log("HEADERS: " + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
  //res.setEncoding('utf8');

  res.on("data", function (chunk) {
    console.log("BODY: " + chunk);
  });
});

req.end();
```

Comment: Pffffff, I tested with `www.warframe.wikia.com` and it also didn't work.... well, that fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `http://` from the host

> host: "warframe.wikia.com",

And add a `/` before the path as root directory

> path: '/wiki/Mods_2.0'

Hope it will work, see it in previous question [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6968448/where-is-body-in-a-nodejs-http-get-response)