# Getting the HTML source of a page in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, webpack

I'm currently struggling to get the HTML source of a webpage in NodeJS due to cors restrictions. Using JQuery I'm making a GET request to a page expecting an HTML response. This however throws the error `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.reddit.com/. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' is therefore not allowed access`. Is there a way to bypass CORS using NodeJS? (like via proxy)

```
        $.ajax({
        url: 'https://www.reddit.com/',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'text/html',
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": '*'
        },
        type: "GET",
        data: {
        },
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);    
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("error");
        }
    });
```

I'm also using webpack dev server with the following headers

```
    headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": '*',
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Node.js / Express, how do I "download" a page and gets its HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801453/in-node-js-express-how-do-i-download-a-page-and-gets-its-html)

Comment: Don't use jQuery, use either the Node.js `http` module or a wrapper for it like the npm package `superagent`

Comment: Try instead just using `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.reddit.com/`for your $.ajax url, and for an explanation, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource/42744707#42744707

Comment: Are you trying to get content by scraping Reddit? I'm fairly sure you'd be better off using their API.

Comment: This question should have been titled how to bypass CORS in a front end request

Answer (score 1):

Do not use jquery in nodejs, you can use this libs to archieve what you need:

- [isomorphic-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/isomorphic-fetch)
- [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request)

Hope it helps